# Testing StarTeam operations

Tags: java, unit-testing, starteam

In a Java application I need to checkout files from Borland Starteam 2006 R2 using Starteam API by various parameters (date, label). Is there any framework that helps to write automatic tests for such functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any; the approach i'd take is a project which has sample files you can checkout by various criteria, and then verify everything you expected arrived, and it is the right file (hash matches).

You're aware that they ship a command line client (stcmd) too, right? For a lot of things, you don't need to use the api at all.